# ListView OnClick within AppWidget

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to make a scrollable stick note widget like [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.clarendon128.android.widget.stickynote&hl=en_US).

For that I'm using a ListView with only one item. The user should be able to click anywhere on the widget to edit the text and some other settings. But I don't know how to add an OnClick listener for the empty space of the listview. So when you tap on that area nothing happens.

I already tried giving my root view an onClick listener, but that doesn't work if there's a view on top of it. Is there a fix for that?

Here's how I added the listener:

```java
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget, getPendingSelfIntent(context, CLICK_TAG));
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(id, remoteViews);

public PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NoteWidget.class);
        intent.setAction(action + id);
        intent.putExtra(NoteWidget.EXTRA_ID, id);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    }
```

This is the layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/widget"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewWidget"
        style="@android:style/Widget.AbsListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/colorText"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</FrameLayout>
```